# How to consume a REST web service in WSO2 Developer Studio ?

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2, Can anyone of you please tell the process of consuming a web service using WSO2 developer studio ? and how i can transform the output to xml format from JSON ?

Thank you,
Sampath.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly WSO2 developer studio is eclipse based IDE, so if you have used eclipse earlier it will be easier for you to understand.
Secondly , it is used to develop WSO2 code, now there are 2 options, either build a CAR file and add it in wso2 esb directly or connect to wso2 esb directly from eclipse and then upload the CAR file.
Lastly , if your output is JSON and you need  XML as the response then use property mediator as

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
<property name="contentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Service) explains on how you can send a message to a service. Also the steps takes you through how it can be done in the WSO2 Developer Studio.

If you want to directly transform JSON to XML without any changes you can use the below two properties,

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

But if you want to transform from JSON to XML with changes to the final payload you can use [payload factory mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/PayloadFactory+Mediator).